# How to speed up Android Studio on my Macbook Pro 2013 16GB RAM & 480GB SSD

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, genymotion

I am currently using Macbook Pro 2013 (2.5 GHz Intel Core i5), 16GB Ram (1600 MHz DDR3), 480GB SSD and Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536 MB.

My problem is, I am having a hard time on Android Studio's (Version 3.5.1) "Slowness" especially when I am running/compiling my assignment to a third-party emulator. I used Genymotion 3.0.3 as my emulator and installed the Google Pixel 2 Device with 9.0 API 28 (1080x1920 - 420 Density) but it takes too long to open and run. ANDDD, IT'S SUPER DUPER LAGGY. ANDDD "System UI isn't responding" always shown.

Anyway, I haven't tried using/installing the Android Studio's built in emulator. Because based on "my research" it is better/recommended to use a third-party emulator specifically, Genymotion.

I thought, upgrading my MBP to 16gb ram (from 4gb ram) and to SSD (from HDD) would really faster my activity/task. Is it not enough? What would you advice?

Answer (score 1):

Android 9.0 support in Genymotion Desktop is known to be slow on macOS. The simplest solution for now is to create an Android 8.0 virtual device instead.